# How to use PyTorch to calculate the gradients of outputs w.r.t. the inputs in a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, gradient, pytorch

I have a trained network. And I want to calculate the gradients of outputs w.r.t. the **inputs**. By querying the PyTorch Docs, **torch.autograd.grad** may be useful.
So, I use the following code:

```
    x_test = torch.randn(D_in,requires_grad=True)
    y_test = model(x_test)
    d = torch.autograd.grad(y_test, x_test)[0]
```

`model` is the neural network. `x_test` is the input of size `D_in` and `y_test` is a scalar output.
I want to compare the calculated result with numerical difference by `scipy.misc.derivative`.
So, I calculated the partial derivate by setting a index.

```
    idx = 3
    x_test = torch.randn(D_in,requires_grad=True)
    y_test = model(x_test)
    print(x_test[idx].item())
    d = torch.autograd.grad(y_test, x_test)[0]
    print(d[idx].item())
    def fun(x):
        x_input = x_test.detach()
        x_input[idx] = x
        with torch.no_grad():
            y = model(x_input)
        return y.item()
    x0 = x_test[idx].item()
    print(x0)
    print(derivative(fun, x0, dx=1e-6))
```

But I got totally different results.
The gradient calculated by `torch.autograd.grad` is `-0.009522666223347187`,
while that by `scipy.misc.derivative` is `-0.014901161193847656`.

Is there anything wrong about the calculation? Or I use `torch.autograd.grad` wrongly?

Comment: I am implementing the integrated gradients, and calculating the same thing gradient of output w.r.t. input. Could you please explain to me what type both the input and output have in your case?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is very likely that your given code is completely correct.
Let me explain this by redirecting you to a little background information on backpropagation, or rather in this case Automatic Differentiation (AutoDiff).

The specific implementation of many packages is based on AutoGrad, a common technique to get the **exact** derivatives of a function/graph. It can do this by essentially "inverting" the forward computational pass to compute piece-wise derivatives of atomic function blocks, like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc., and then "chaining them together". 
I explained AutoDiff and its specifics in a more detailed answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054627/pytorch-autograd-automatic-differentiation-feature/51055391#51055391).

On the contrary, scipy's derivative function is only an **approximation** to this derivative by using finite differences. You would take the results of the function at close-by points, and then calculate a derivative based on the difference in function values for those points. This is why you see a slight difference in the two gradients, since this can be an inaccurate representation of the actual derivative.