# PyTorch derivative has no degree

Tags: python, pytorch

I am studying the tutorial from `PyTorch` official [docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html). I am trying to understand the content. Start from `You can do many crazy things with autograd!`

```
x = torch.randn(3, requires_grad=True)
y = x * 2

i = 0
while y.data.norm() < 100:
    y = y * 2
    i+= 1

print(x)
print(y)
print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([-0.6933,  0.1126,  0.3913], requires_grad=True)
tensor([-88.7455,  14.4082,  50.0871], grad_fn=<MulBackward>)
6
```

Find the derivative w.r.t to `x` at point `[0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]`

```
gradients = torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], dtype=torch.float)
y.backward(gradients)
print(x.grad)
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([ 12.8000, 128.0000,   0.0128])
```

In my understanding `i` equals to `6`. Then `y = (2x)^7` and derivative is different from `PyTorch`. It has `7` as a factor when substitute the value
to my derivative.

The answer from the `PyTorch` is simply substitute `x` with given point to the `dy/dx = 2^7 * x`

**Question:**

How to derive the derivative?

**References:**

[How to use PyTorch to calculate partial derivatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500010/how-to-use-pytorch-to-calculate-partial-derivatives)

[PyTorch Autograd automatic differentiation feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054627/pytorch-autograd-automatic-differentiation-feature/51055391#51055391)

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the expressions, it'd turn out that `y = x * (2^7)`, the derivative of which is `2^7 * x` .

Comment: `y = x * 2^7`. Has derivative w.r.t x is `2^7`. Since `x` is first degree. It am thinking about chain rule, but I couldn't be able to figure out. Because it has just 2 variables.

Comment: @backothermoon It is no need to do chain rule here since the derivative is just `x` and `y`. Therefore total derivative and partial derivative is the same thing.